# chrome extension force install outside Chrome Web Store

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-workspace

**How to force install a self hosted chrome extension in my organization?**

I went over the requirements detailed in the official [documentation](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1pT0ZSbGdrbGvuCsVD2jjxrw-GVz-80rMS2dgkkquhTY/edit#heading=h.gb2ntk6856ld).

I have packed the extension with Chrome's "pack extension" button, hosting it in a publicly accessible location, headers are as required. The extension is very basic.
Works when I load it (unpacked), when I manually download it, it shows "package is invalid, CRX proof required" which is fine, because it's not from the Web Store.
To force deploy it I use the google admin panel (Adding the extension by ID from a custom URL)

Any further ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Search for the following setting in your Google Admin Portal:

"Allow insecure extension packaging", set it to "Allow insecurely packaged extensions" and try again.

Answer (score 0):

I just went through this and while my steps are rough I wanted to at least leave this for someone else bumping into this in the future.

Please note that in the file contents you will need to replace things like `<IDGoesHere>` with the appropriate value you document as you go through the steps.

### For deployment to windows based systems you can do the following:

- In the browser where you have your unpacked extension loaded, navigate to `chrome://extensions/` and select the **Pack Extension** button.
- For the `Extension root directory` browse to the directory where your unpacked extension is stored
- Click the **Pack Extension** button
- Don't worry about setting a Private key file at this time
- Now you will have a crx and pem file saved into the directory above the directory that contained the source code for your extension
- Drag and drop the crx file onto google chrome and let it install the extension from the crx file
- You will now have your extension installed twice, once unpacked and once from the crx file
- The extension won't be able to be disabled as Chrome will indicate it is not from the web store, document the value next to `ID:` for the crx installed extension, not the unpacked version which should have a different ID
- Serve up the crx file via https from some web server you have access to and note the url for the crx file
- Create a file named `manifest.xml` with the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gupdate xmlns="http://www.google.com/update2/response" protocol="2.0">
    <app appid="<IDGoesHere>">
        <updatecheck codebase="<URLToCRXFileGoesHere>" version="0.0.1"/>
    </app>
</gupdate>
```

- Serve up the manifest file via https from some web server you have access to and note the url for the manifest.xml file
- Create a ExtensionInstall.reg file with the following

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome\ExtensionSettings\<IDGoesHere>]
"installation_mode"="normal_installed"
"toolbar_pin"="default_unpinned"
"update_url"="<UrlToManifestXMLFileGoesHere>"
"override_update_url"=dword:00000001
```

- Remove the extension that was loaded via the crx file from your google chrome
- Open the .reg file with the registry editor and let it create the appropriate registry keys
- Close and reopen chrome and if all the steps worked you should now see a copy of your extension that is loaded and enabled and that has the ID of the crx version you noted earlier
- Run the same reg file on whatever other windows systems you want to load the extension on to

There are similar processes for loading extensions on macOS and linux.

Updating the app should be as easy as generating a new crx file using the .pem file that was saved from before and updating the manifest and crx files.

The [Managing Extensions in your Enterprise pdf](https://storage.googleapis.com/support-kms-prod/TYq1FnEDxENq9EFFlRHdMk8l1lrGDSb5S6Iz?sjid=9598541652615835869-NA) from google support has more detail about the overall process and the more complete list of possible ways to accomplish this.